# What does syntax in example code mean (typescript, react)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

```
const example: (string: string) => string = string => {
  return string.split("");
}
```

Its not a detailed question - I know, but I couldnt think of another way to ask and I simply do not understand what is happening in the below code.
I only understand only string as type is accepted, but how is this even a function -shouldnt it be:

```
const example = (string:string) => return string.split("")}
```

instead ?
Thanks!!

UPDATE:
There was some miscommunication maybe. I only want to understand the following (in bold letters):

```
const example**: (string: string) => string** = string => {
  return string.split("");
}
```

1. why is it ":" and not "="?
2. what is:      => string = string =>
   why not just = string =>
   ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, actually there's a type error, it should be:

```
const example: (string: string) => string[] = string => {
  return string.split("");
}
```

instead of `(string: string) => string` because `string.split()` will return an array.

also, it's better to rename the argument to something other than `string` as it can be easily confused with the type `string`.

Here's a fixed version:

```
const example: (someArg: string) => string[] = (someString) => {
  return someString.split('');
};
```

So, the function `example` simply takes an argument (of type `string`) and returns an array of strings that is indicated by `(string: string) => string[]`.

You can also use the below syntax if you find above a bit confusing:

```
const example2 = (someString: string): string[] => {
    return someString.split('');
};
```

**Update:**

Considering this `(string: string) => string`,

> why is it ":" and not "="?

It is not `=` because we're not yet assigning the value. We're still in the process of assigning the type. After giving the type, `=` is used to finally give it a value (which is an arrow function).

> what is: => string = string => why not just = string => ?

TypeScript does understand that the returned value is an array of strings but `=> string[]` is used to explicitly mention the return type (to make sure that the function always returns what we want it to return), we use `=>` to separate the argument types and return type. Think of this as an arrow function like syntax for giving the type to a function.

Comment: thank you, that wasnt my question wich was more about the syntax. I updated my question, maybe I wasnt clear enough

Comment: @juliascoding I know that it might be confusing but think of it this way, everything after `=` is the value of example(which is an arrow function) and everything in between(`(someArg: string) => string[]`) is the type of that function(which not only consists of the argument type but also the type of the returned value)

Comment: Thank you very much. ok so 1.) after the ":"  (example: (someArg: string)) is not the actual function but typescript specifying, argument expected should be a string. 2.)"=> string = string" has typo like you said and should be "string[] = (someString)", here typescript specifies NOT the argument BUT the return type?!Which in this case would be an array of strings but what stands "someString" for?

Comment: @juliascoding Yep, that's correct. `someString` is the actual argument. Naming it as `string` as you did in your question is not a good practice as `string` is also used for the type.

Answer (score 1):

This is the type:

```
               vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
const example: (someArg: string) => string[] = (someString) => {
  return someString.split('');
};
```

A function taking a string and returning a string.
Everything after the equals sign is the value.

Comment: ah so function takes a string, returns a string and then doesn something else (in this case split) with that returned string?! Also why is it ":" and not =, like how is that a function (const example: and not const example=)?

Answer (score -1):

You can use arrow function methodology in typescripts. It is a common way in most programming language for make more easy to read.

It is just a syntax. In background typescript will convert this method to vanilla function version.

your above code look like below code. There are many ways to write the same method different versions.

```
    // you can write like this 
    function example( string: string ){
      return string.split("");
    }

    // If you need to write multiple lines you should use circle brackets
    const example = ( str : string ) => {
        // do something here...
        return str.split("");
    }
    // if you don't need to write multiple lines you can return like this.
    const example = ( str : string ) => str.split("");
   
   // But If you want to use return syntax. you can do. it is up to you.
   const example = ( str : string ) => return str.split("");
```

If you give more detail. I can help you and apologize for my english.

If I misunderstand sorry about that.